# ng-bind: concatination of two values with double colons

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind

How can we use `ng-bind` when there is a concatination of two values with double colons?

```
<title ng-bind="::AppConfig.SITE_TITLE + ::AppConfig.PAGE_TITLE"></title>
```

Above code returns this error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression at column 24 of the expression [AppConfig.SITE_TITLE + ::AppConfig.PAGE_TITLE] starting at [::AppConfig.PAGE_TITLE].
```

Note that this works fine:

```
<title ng-bind="::AppConfig.SITE_TITLE + ' | This is page title'"></title>
```

Comment: _"Note that this works fine"_ : You know how it works and still ask a question??? Am I missing something?

Comment: @zeroflagL yes.but the question is valid..why the first one is not working..

Comment: @zeroflagL, the first case uses two angular variables with one time binding syntax, however the second case uses a static string in place of second variable.

Comment: @PankajParkar The question is "How can we use", not "Why is this not working"

Comment: @pravee-n The first one is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `<title ng-bind="::(AppConfig.SITE_TITLE + AppConfig.PAGE_TITLE)"></title>`

Answer (score 0):

Could use expressions instead of ng-bind

```
<title>{{::AppConfig.SITE_TITLE}} | {{::AppConfig.PAGE_TITLE}}</title>
```